# open extracted location after extracting

Tags: winrar

Is there a way in WinRar to quickly go to the containing folder of the extracted files directly after I have extracted them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Extraction path and options]

Comment: Dude! I'm blind!

Comment: This answer should be updated; the image is no longer available.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Seems like somebody mass-edited `i.imgur.com` to `i.stack.imgur.com` without actually reuploading the images. Fixed post.

Comment: It is strange, as the image you used on March (the second revision) was http://i.stack.imgur.com/qgh2U.png. I thought the images on i.stack.imgur were always available, and I hope this doesn't mean I have to periodically check the images I used in my questions are still visible, and re-add them if they aren't.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It originally was http://i.imgur.com/qgh2U.png, on the main server, not Stack's. IIRC, someone had done a huge database edit, replacing the hostname on all such links.

Comment: I got it. Yes, that was a background edit done once, when they changed the server for the images, and passed to a dedicated one that should not lose images. If the URL was changed without having the image re-uploaded, the database edit doesn't make sense, though. I am glad to know we can trust the images on i.stack.imgur.com to always be present.